@firestore_fn.on_document_created limit on firebase cloud functions(2nd gen)
I am a beginner. and I am sorry that my English is not good.
I am programming using firestore, firebase cloud functions(2nd gen).
I am asking about @firestore_fn.on_document_created limit of firebase cloud functions(2nd gen).
Question 1.
Is there no limit on the number of event not yet to trigger the cloud function?
For example, if there are a billion event and one instance of cloud function, do all events trigger the cloud function at least once, even if late?
Question 2.
Does request timeout mean the time from the moment the event triggers a function to the moment it completes its mission?
Or does it mean the time from the moment the event occurs to the moment the function completes its mission?
Thank you for reading my question of beginner in program.

I get an answer from the Firebase team, so I leave it below.

In general, quotas for Cloud Functions encompass 3 areas:
Resource Limits – These affect the total amount of resources your
functions can consume. Time Limits – These affect how long things can
run. Rate Limits – These affect the rate at which you can call the
Cloud Functions API to manage your functions.   Question 1: Event
Backlog and Triggering – There's no hard limit on the number of events
that can be queued up before triggering a Cloud Function. Firebase
will try to process all events eventually, even if there's a large
backlog.
When your, e.g. rate limits exceed, then they won’t drop events.If
they did, that would be exceptionally bad, and your app would not
scale.
Rate limits are in place to prevent a massive update from spinning
up potentially millions of instances concurrently. Instead, Cloud
Functions will limit the maximum concurrent number of invocations, and
force all the events to go through that max instead of trying to
handle them all at the same time. The events will be processed as fast
as your function can deal with them, within that concurrent maximum.
More → here.
Question 2: Request Timeout – The request timeout refers to the time
from the moment the event triggers your Cloud Function to the moment
the function completes its execution.
The default timeout for Cloud Functions is 60 seconds. You can
configure this up to 540 seconds (9 minutes) in the Firebase console.
If your function exceeds the timeout, it will be terminated, and any
unfinished work will be lost.
Important Consideration – Because of the "at least once" delivery
guarantee, it's crucial to design your Cloud Functions to be
idempotent. This means that if a function is triggered multiple times
for the same event, it should produce the same result without causing
unintended side effects.
While Firebase will try to process all events eventually, it's
important to be aware of the potential for delays and to design your
Cloud Functions to handle these situations gracefully.



Is there no limit on the number of event not yet to trigger the cloud
function?
For example, if there are a billion event and one instance of cloud
function, do all events trigger the cloud function at least once, even
if late?

Yes, the system strives to handle all events.  Some events might be dropped if they can be handled after a very long amount of time.

Does request timeout mean the time from the moment the event triggers
a function to the moment it completes its mission?
Or does it mean the time from the moment the event occurs to the
moment the function completes its mission?

The timeout refers to the amount of time spend handling the event in the server instance, not from the time the event was first generated.


I am asking about @firestore_fn.on_document_created limit of firebase cloud functions(2nd gen).

As per the Documentation seems only one event will be handled at a time.
For Question 1.

Is there no limit on the number of event not yet to trigger the cloud function?

According to the Documentation

Cloud Functions provides at-least-once execution of an event-driven function for each event emitted by an event source. By default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the function is not invoked again and the event is dropped.

For that you can enable retries on an event-driven function.

Cloud Functions retries a failed function invocation until it completes successfully or the retry window expires. This retry window expires after 24 hours. Cloud Functions retries newly created event-driven functions using an exponential backoff strategy, with an increasing backoff of between 10 and 600 seconds.

Also make sure to set an end condition to avoid infinite retry loops.
For Question 2.

Does request timeout mean the time from the moment the event triggers a function to the moment it completes its mission?

The cloud functions 2nd gen was built on Google cloud run. The request timeout setting specifies the time within which a response must be returned by services deployed to Cloud Run.

For Cloud Run services, the request timeout setting specifies the time within which a response must be returned by services deployed to Cloud Run. If a response isn't returned within the time specified, the request ends and an error 504 is returned.

